# How do I fix the Python error that I get with my Gregory-Liebniz equation?

Tags: python, math, syntax-error

```
n = 10  
pi =0

for i in n:  
    pi = pi + (4i - (1**i))/(2i+1)

print(pi)
```

There is an indent in the for loop, can't get it to show.  I comes up as a syntax error at pi = pi... line.  What would be a good way to figure this out?  I'm just learning Python and am not fully sure if I am using correct syntax.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Replace `4i` and `2i` with `4*i` and `2*i`

Comment: and `for i in n:` with `for i in range(n):`

Comment: Also what are you expecting `1**i` to do? Because that raises `1` to the power of `i`, which will always result in `1`.

Comment: BTW, this is _not_ the Gregory–Leibniz formula for pi. Also, the actual Gregory–Leibniz formula is one of the slowest ways known of calculating pi.

Comment: @Stacey: 
 [Accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped, for others taking reference for the same problem in future.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code:

```
n = 10  
pi = 0

for i in range(n): # replaced 'n' with range(n)  
    pi += (4*i - ((-1)**i))/(2*i+1)  # a = a + b, is same as: a += b
    #              ^ Correction as per Gregory–Leibniz formula    
    # for multiplication, you need to explicitly mention `*` operator
    # replaced '4i' and '2i' with '4*i' and '2*i'

print(pi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the actual formula:

```
n = 1000 # Raise the number of iterations to get a better approximation
pi = 0.0

for i in range(n):
    pi += (-1)**i/(2.0*i + 1) # You have to use the .0 in python 2.x

print(pi * 4)
```

The formula returns `pi/4`, that's why the `* 4` part.

Also, `1**i` always results in `1`, you actually need `(-1)**i`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the syntax errors of `4i` and `2i`, you have not implemented the Gregory–Leibniz formula for pi correctly. Here's a repaired version.

```
n = 50000
pi = 0
for i in range(n):
    pi += 4 * (-1)**i / (2*i + 1)

print(pi)
```

**output**

```
3.1415726535897814
```

However, `(-1)**i` is a very wasteful way to compute the sign change of each term. Here's a better way. It's also more efficient to move the multiplication by 4 out of the loop, and to get `range` to just supply odd numbers.

```
n = 50000
pi = 0
s = 1
for i in range(1, 2*n, 2):
    pi += s / i
    s = -s
pi *= 4

print(pi)
```

---

The Gregory–Leibniz formula calculates `pi = 4 * arctan(1)`. You can speed up the convergence by using arctangent relationships based on smaller numbers than 1. Eg,

```
arctan(1) = arctan(1/2) + arctan(1/3)
```

and

```
arctan(1) = 4 * arctan(1/5) - arctan(1/239)
```

It can be more convenient to use the inverse cotangent function, since `arctan(1/n) == arccot(n)`

```
def arc_cot(n, lim=1E-15):
    ''' Inverse cotangent of n '''
    x = 1.0 / n
    y = -x * x
    a = x
    i = 1
    while True:
        i += 2
        x *= y
        t = x / i
        a += t
        if abs(t) < lim:
            break
    return a

a = arc_cot(2) + arc_cot(3) 
print(4 * a)

a = 4 * arc_cot(5) - arc_cot(239) 
print(4 * a)
```

**output**

```
3.141592653589793
3.141592653589794
```

For info on the derivation of these arccot formulae, please see [Machin-like formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) and [Computing Pi: Lists Of Machin-Type (Inverse Cotangent) Identities For Pi/4](http://www.machination.eclipse.co.uk/).